# FPGA Frequency Domain Based Beidou-3 B2a Coarse Acquisition Processor Using FFT

Tags: fpga, fft, gnss

I'm using an ARM+FPGA platform to capture B2a (BeiDou or COMPASS) signals and determine the user position, velocity and precise time (PVT). The C/A frequency of B2a is 10.23MHz. If my sample rate is 20.46MHz, then I should do 32768 points-FFT by FPGA. Give me advise about how to achieve it.

Comment: You have to write a 32768 point FFT in VHDL or Verilog. There is code on the web but I am not sure if there is code for a 32768 point one. Unless you are experienced in writing HDL code it is a non trivial task. You can buy one, the last price I saw was $40.000. Beyond that, I don't think this forum can help you here. (Ah: don't forget you will need a window function as well)

Comment: Why do you need to do the FFT?

Comment: @PKP The length of C/A code is  10230 chips(or 1ms). The Doppler frequency and code phase of satellite signals are searched sequentially costs so much time, so I want to use the fft to search parallelly, which can reduce the time of acquire satellite signals dranarucally.

Comment: @oldfart Thank you very much. Forgive me for my poor English(I am a student from China).  Haha，$40.000 means a lot to me, because  I can't afford it.

Comment: Are you sure FFT is the proper technique for this?  As far as I am aware, beidou signals are quite similar to GPS signals, and most GPS receivers use correlators to receive the signal. If you really need to do FFT, then you may need to do a bit of engineering and put together a more customized FFT component.  After all, you can process samples in blocks at a much higher clock rate than the sample rate and you probably don't need to consider all of the outputs of a full FFT.

Comment: @alex.forencich Thank you for your answer. I am working on correlators now, but the C/A length of B2a is 10230 chips that is 10 times than B1I(or L1I, the C/A length is 1023 chips), which means I should take 10 times more to seach B2a C/A phase. FFT is the way I saw in the paper to reduce the search time, but I have no idea how to ahieve it.
By the way, if the 32K point FFT was completed, how can I find the maximum of the results by FPGA?

Comment: Comparator tree.  See http://archvlsi.ics.forth.gr/muqpro/cmpTree_hart_tr304.ps for some options on building these.

Answer (score 1):

Not immediately an answer but I can't get a picture in comments. It may give you an idea of what it takes to implement a 32K point FFT. I just pushed a 32K streaming FFT through Vivado. These are the result for a xc7z020clg400-1 (synthesis only):
[image]

Vivado could not fit all memory in block rams so it started using LUTs as memories.

As a background: the $40K was a quote from an IP provider to the company I worked for.

Comment: wow, 32K point FFT costs 35788 LUTs, if instantiates more FFT modules, that is need a expensive FPGA!

Comment: Why would you need more? This is a streaming FFT which process a sample every clock cycle continously.